# ExtJS checking value of a cell before submitting

Tags: events, extjs

I have a column named event_date. I want to warn the user if he trys to submit the info without filling up the event_date column and prevent further execution. Here is how I define my column:

```
header: 'Event_date',
            width: 115,
            dataIndex: 'event_time',
            renderer: this._renderExactDate,
            field: {
                type: 'textfield'
            }
```

and my render function is:

```
_renderExactDate: function(date) {
        if (date == '0000-00-00 00:00:00' || date == undefined) {
            Ext.MessageBox.show({
            title: 'New event',
            msg: 'You must set a date',
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
        });
      } 
      else
          {
              return date;
          }
    }
```

but obv. renderer is not the way to do this, yet I haven't found a way to do this.

thanks

Leron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is using ExtJS4 then you should make use of the [model field validations](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-validations) field to set the accepted format. Write a custom one if any of the standards don't fit the bill. Then you can check if the model is valid before any attempts to sync and flag a warning accordingly.

The event you want to hook into is this one. Then you can get the record/model and check its 'isValid' method before generating your warning.

Link: [Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing validateedit](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-validateedit) event

Comment: Yes, its ExtJS4 but I wonder isn't there way to listen for some event like blur() and when the focus is out of this field to trigger a function which shall check if the filed is left empty? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I've added the link to the event you want in the solution.

Comment: Haha cheers for pointing that out. Had linked to my local copy. Oops!

Comment: Lol, the link is still not working but maybe the problem is in me, dunno. Thanks anyways. I accepted your answer.